The whois feature in TL is currently broken
There's a feature that lists and summons mods for a specific site on the teacher's lounge. Currently, it also lists staff with diamonds, which breaks inter site moderator collaboration. Here's an example command (mod only link) for reference.
It also occasionally seems to fail completely.
Could this be fixed please?

For non-moderators, this post contains a screenshot of how the command is supposed to work.

For reference, it looks like it fails when the message generated would be longer than the character limit. The whois bot should probably be exempt from the character limit, because it's entirely possible that SO will reach the point where the whois command legitimately creates a longer message.

@Sonic regarding your edit, I expect title in images (and would wait to read it) but not in links, so I added it as plain text as well.

@Mithical That's a fair point. I've opened a PR to make that change. I would expect that to be merged by the time we've reached that point

(There's also a PR to fix the actual issue at hand here, so this should be back to working soon)

Fixed now (mod only link).
This broke when we moved Chat to GCP (a.k.a. the Cloud) on Tuesday.
Chat gets the list of employees via a private API from meta.SE, and because chat and meta no longer live next to each other, such private API calls are a little more demanding (because they can't be made over the public internet). This particular API call wasn't set up quite correctly and thus it failed.
That's why the whois bot listed everyone -- it didn't know who the employees were.

More important: is the Wheel of Blame still working? :D

@ShadowWizard I just tested to make sure and it does! We don't really use chat.MSE for internal chat anymore, we're all on Slack these days, and over there it's a different (slightly less elaborate) wheel of blame: https://github.com/balpha/wheelofblame

Another one for you? (Looks like similar symptoms. :))
